# running hadoop program on a linux machine

Tags: java, linux, hadoop

I have strated working on hadoop systems and first assignment is to calculate the maximum temperature of a geo location over past 100 years . I'm done with everything from installing java and hadoop but i'm not getting my output folder after this final command

```
~/.linuxbrew/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.0$ hadoop jar MaxTemperature.jar /ncdc/sample.txt output
```

the console is not showing any error also

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be found the directory `/user/hduser/output` on HDFS. Change hduser by the hadoop user run the command.

In the command, output is a relative path, in this case, relative to HDFS user home directory.